# Angular, white screen appears for one or two seconds before displaying the page

Tags: angular

I'm new with angular 4. I have created some components:

- HomeComponent
- AboutComponent
- NewsComponent
- CpntactComponent

and I have applied a [bootstrap template](https://blackrockdigital.github.io/startbootstrap-modern-business/) to my first project.

I have no error but the problem is that when I navigate between page , a white screen appears for 1 or 2 seconds before displaying the page.

**index.html**

```
<body>
    <app-root></app-root>
</body>
```

This is the **app.component.html**

```
<app-nav-bar></app-nav-bar>

<router-outlet></router-outlet>

<app-footer></app-footer>
```

**Project structure**

[image: Project]

**for exemple , I'm in the homepage :**

[image]

**when I click on link about , this white creen appears for 1 or 2 seconds :**

[image]

**and then the page is displayed:**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that I forgot to add **"routerLink"** inside the links like this for example:

```
<a routerLink="contact">
```

Answer (score 1):

This is typical Angular behavior, especially in development with JIT compilation, as it's a pretty heavyweight framework. If you use AOT compilation and a bundler like Webpack, the issue is greatly reduced. You may still notice a brief delay on bootstrapping the app, but you can add a loading screen, if you want.

Comment: The problem is that I forgot to add "routerLink" inside the links like this for example <a routerLink="contact">